# Periodicity of the sequence of ideals generared by the entries of the maps in minimal free resolution of modules over complete intersection ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, free-modules, gorenstein

For a finitely generated module $M$ over a Noetherian local ring  $(R,\mathfrak m)$, let $I_i^R(M)$ denote the ideal generated by the entries in a matrix representation of $\partial_i$, where $(F_i,\partial_i)$ is a minimal $R$-free resolution of $M$.

Now let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a regular local ring and $x_1,...,x_n\in \mathfrak m$ be an $R$-regular sequence. Then, is it true that for every finitely generated $R/(x_1,...,x_n)$-module $N$, the sequence of ideals $I_i^{R/(x_1,...,x_n)}(N)$ are  eventually periodic.